# Angularjs Filter data with dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am kinda new in angularjs and javascript so please be kind, I have two dropdown items (Ionic Select) both of them holds data from a service. The issue is that I need to filter them in order to work together like: if I choose a company in the first dropdown list, only the reps inside of that company should display in the other dropdown list.

I tried using `| filter: byID` as I followed in Angularjs documentation but I do not think it is the right way of doing this don't know.

HTML:

```
<label class="item item-input item-select"">
    <div class="input-label">
      Company:
    </div>
    <select>
      <option ng-repeat="x in company">{{x.compname}}</option>
      <option selected>Select</option>      
    </select>
  </label>
   <div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">
      Rep:
    </div>
    <select>
       <option ng-repeat="x in represent">{{x.repname}}</option>
      <option selected>Select</option>
    </select>
  </label>
```

Javascript:

```
/*=========================Get All Companies=========================*/
 $http.get("http://localhost:15021/Service1.svc/GetAllComp")
      .success(function(data) {

        var obj = data;
        var SComp = [];


    angular.forEach(obj, function(index, element) {

    angular.forEach(index, function(indexN, elementN) {        

        SComp.push({compid: indexN.CompID, compname: indexN.CompName});

        $scope.company = SComp;
    });    

    });          
            })
/*=========================Get All Companies=========================*/

/*=========================Get All Reps=========================*/
 $http.get("http://localhost:15021/Service1.svc/GetAllReps")
      .success(function(data) {

        var obj = data;
        var SReps = [];


    angular.forEach(obj, function(index, element) {

    angular.forEach(index, function(indexN, elementN) {        

        SReps.push({repid: indexN.RepID, repname: indexN.RepName, fkc :indexN.fk_CompID});

        $scope.represent = SReps;
    });    

    });          
            })
/*=========================Get All Reps=========================*/
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may solve this problem like my solution process:
my solution like your problem. at first show **District** list and show **Thana** list according to **selected District**. using **filter** expression

**In HTML:**

```
<div>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3"><label><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-fw"></i> District List</label></div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDist" ng-options="district.name for district in districts">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3"><label><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-fw"></i> Thana List</label></div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedThana" ng-options="thana.name for thana in thanas | filter: filterExpression">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**In controller:**

```
            $scope.selectedDist={};
            $scope.districts = [
                {id: 1, name: 'Dhaka'},
                {id: 2, name: 'Goplaganj'},
                {id: 3, name: 'Faridpur'}
            ];

            $scope.thanas = [
                {id: 1, name: 'Mirpur', dId: 1},
                {id: 2, name: 'Uttra', dId: 1},
                {id: 3, name: 'Shahabag', dId: 1},
                {id: 4, name: 'Kotalipara', dId: 2},
                {id: 5, name: 'Kashiani', dId: 2},
                {id: 6, name: 'Moksedpur', dId: 2},
                {id: 7, name: 'Vanga', dId: 3},
                {id: 8, name: 'faridpur', dId: 3}
            ];
            $scope.filterExpression = function(thana) {
                return (thana.dId === $scope.selectedDist.id );
            };
```

***N.B:*** Here **filterExpression** is a custom function that return values when selected district id equal dId in thana.

Comment: Does your solution work entirely? The reason I ask is the  filterExpression in your filter selfs does not call the id from your controller. @shaishabroy

Comment: The solution should work because filterExpression call for each thana object and it return true of false value. You can check in [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/5CoVo75Es6qP5rBcP4FX?p=preview)

Comment: If my solution solved your problem please accept this solution @RenaldoGeldenhuis

Comment: worked charm ,just 2 hours b4 my production release. tradeOffs ,the filter keeps on calling ,you can see it ,if you log it .so a silent digest cycle will keep running behind the scene ,it's fine with small data set but not with large data set

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope,$window, $http) {
   $scope.myFunc = function(x) {
  $scope.name = x.Name;
  $scope.country = x.Country;
  $scope.city = x.City;
  $scope.x = x;
  $("#myModal").modal();
   };
   
   $scope.saveData = function(x) {
  if(x == ''){
   x = angular.copy($scope.names[0]);
   x.Name = $scope.name;
   x.Country = $scope.country;
   x.City = $scope.city;
   $scope.names.push(x);
  }
  else{
   x.Name = $scope.name;
   x.Country = $scope.country; 
   x.City = $scope.city; 
  }
 };
  
  $scope.newData = function() {
  $scope.name = "";
  $scope.country = "";
  $scope.city = "";
  $scope.x = "";
  $("#myModal").modal();
   };

 $scope.myDelete = function(x) {
  if(x.Name=='' && x.Country=='' && x.City==''){
   var index = $scope.names.indexOf(x);
   $scope.names.splice(index, 1);
  }
  else{
   var deletedata = $window.confirm('are you absolutely sure you want to delete?');
   if (deletedata) {
   alert('i am');
    var index = $scope.names.indexOf(x);
    $scope.names.splice(index, 1);    
   }
  }
 };
 $scope.filterExpression = function(x) {
    //alert($scope.country.id);
                return (x.countryId === $scope.country.countryId );
            };
   
   $scope.names =  [{"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"","Country":""},{"Name":"Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados","City":"","Country":""}]
   $scope.countryList = [
        {countryName : "Pakistan", countryId : 1},
        {countryName : "UK", countryId : 2},
        {countryName : "Sweden", countryId : 3}
    ];
 $scope.cityList = [
        {cityName : "Karachi", cityId : 1, countryId:1},
        {cityName : "London", cityId : 2, countryId:11},
        {cityName : "Sweden City", cityId : 3, countryId:3}
    ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.table tr {
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
 <pre>{{names}}</pre>
  <h2>Hover Rows</h2>
  <p>The .table-hover class enables a hover state on table rows:</p>            
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Sr.No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Country</th>
   <th>City</th>
  <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in names" ng-dblclick="myFunc(x)" >
        <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
  <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
  <td>{{ x.Country.countryName }}</td>
  <td>{{ x.City.cityName }}</td>
  <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="myDelete(x)"></span></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
  <tr ng-click="newData()">
   <td  colspan="4">
   </td>
   <td>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ng-click="newData()" cursor="" ></span>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
 
  </table>
  
    <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" ng-if="x!=''">Edit Record</h4>
    <h4 class="modal-title" ng-if="x==''">Save Record</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
   <label for="name">Name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="country">Country:</label>
   <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="country" ng-model="country"> -->
   <select class="form-control" ng-model="country" ng-options="x.countryName for x in countryList"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="country">City:</label>
   <select class="form-control" ng-model="city" ng-options="x.cityName for x in cityList | filter:filterExpression"></select>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" ng-model="x" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="saveData(x)">Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="myDelete(x)" ng-if="x!=''">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```