# Drop down list filters aren't working

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to filter one drop down list (DDL) based on a selection made in another. I was referencing this question for how to do it: [Angularjs Filter data with dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850379/angularjs-filter-data-with-dropdown)

My DDLs look like this:

```
    <select class="form-control input-sm"
            ng-change="echo(selectedDepartment);"
            ng-model="selectedDepartment"
            ng-options="d as d.DepartmentName for d in departmentList track by d.DepartmentId"></select>
    <select class="form-control input-sm"
            ng-change="echo(selectedTeam);"
            ng-model="selectedTeam"
            ng-options="t as t.TeamName for t in (teamList | filter: filterTeams) track by t.TeamId"></select>
    <select class="form-control input-sm"
            ng-change="echo(selectedRep);"
            ng-model="selectedRep"
            ng-options="r as (r.FirstName + ' ' + r.LastName) for r in (repList | filter: filterReps) track by r.UserId"></select>
```

The `echo` function in `ng-change` is just using `console.log` so I can verify that the model is being updated when a selection is made and it is.

Here are my filter functions:

```
    $scope.filterTeams = function (team) {
        console.log("Team's DeptId: " + team.Department.DepartmentId + "  Selected Dept Id: " + $scope.selectedDepartment.DepartmentId);

        return (team.Department.DepartmentId === $scope.selectedDepartment.DepartmentId);
    };

    $scope.filterReps = function(rep) {
        return (rep.TeamId === $scope.selectedTeam.TeamId);
    };
```

What's strange is that when I reference `$scope.selectedDepartment` in my filter function it's always an empty object even after the echo function running in `ng-change` shows it's been updated.

The filter functions are part of the same controller that the DDLs are referencing and have the same `$scope` object.

When I select a department my team DDL goes blank since it's comparing `team.Department.DepartmentId` to undefined.

How can `$scope.selectedDepartment` be an empty object and be populated at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

For inexplicable reasons you can't use `$scope` in a filter function. So to make this work you have to create a local variable in your controller and copy the value from your `$scope` variable to the local one for the filter function to use. Then everything works.

Here's the updated view:

```
    <select class="form-control input-sm"
            ng-change="updateSelectedDepartment(selectedDepartment);"
            ng-model="selectedDepartment"
            ng-options="d as d.DepartmentName for d in departmentList track by d.DepartmentId"></select>
    <select class="form-control input-sm"
            ng-change="updateSelectedTeam(selectedTeam);"
            ng-model="selectedTeam"
            ng-options="t as t.TeamName for t in (teamList | filter: filterTeams) track by t.TeamId"></select>
    <select class="form-control input-sm"
            ng-model="selectedRep"
            ng-options="r as (r.FirstName + ' ' + r.LastName) for r in (repList | filter: filterReps) track by r.UserId"></select>
```

And here's the relevant sections from the controller:

```
var selectedDepartment = {};
var selectedTeam = {};

$scope.updateSelectedDepartment = function(dept) {
    selectedDepartment = dept;
};

$scope.updateSelectedTeam = function (team) {
    selectedTeam = team;
};

$scope.filterTeams = function (team) {
    return (team.Department.DepartmentId === selectedDepartment.DepartmentId);
};

$scope.filterReps = function (rep) {
    return (rep.Team.TeamId === selectedTeam.TeamId);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option...instead of making the filter a function on your controller, make it an actual filter (the added benefit there is you can reuse the filter in other areas). So do this:

```
.filter('teamsFilter', function() {
    return function(teamsList, selectedDepartment) {
        var out = [];
        angular.forEach(teamsList, function(team) {
            if (team.Department.DepartmentId === selectedDepartment.DepartmentId) {
                out.push(team);
            }
        });
        return out;
    }
})
```

And then use it like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedTeam" 
        ng-options="t as t.TeamName for t in (teamList | teamsFilter: selectedDepartment)"></select>
```